# How to remove background color from rmarkdown knitted file in r?

Tags: r-markdown

All of a sudden today onward all the rmardown notebook files that I knitt have started to get grey background color row before the `Hide` button which used to be clear earlier.

In below pic, On Left is the file saved earlier, On Right is saved file today:

[image]

I am not sure how this happened but today I created a rmarkdown - template package and since then I have noticed this change.

settings I am using

```
---
title: "New Notebook"
output: 
  html_notebook:
    highlight: tango
    df_print: paged
    toc: true
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: false
    number_sections: true
    toc_depth: 6
---
```

```
.scroll-100 {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Have you restarted your RStudio since?  Maybe copy it all to a new document, just to see if it clears? The code I used gave me the one of the left without the **grey** box around the hide button

Comment: Yes @DanielJachetta. I have restarted twice and still getting same issue. Infact yesterday I even got a gibbersih content on saving s knitted file which eventually got fine on knitting again. I guess I will have to try reinstalling Rstudio .